# Setting java bootclasspath

Tags: java, bootclasspath

I have JDK6 & 8 installed on my computer, I would like to do

```
    javac -source 1.6
```

However I have this warning

```
    warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
```

Does anyone know how to set it? I am not using any IDE and I'm on windows7.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** use  -Xbootclasspath and provide all jar files there from your  JDK6's jre/lib directory, but a better way of doing it would be to call javac from your JDK6 installation:

```
<path-to-jdk6>/bin/javac ...
```

Comment: Sorry I have edit my question, I have jdk6& 8 so it would be javac -bootclasspath c/user/.../jdk6/bin/javac ?

Comment: I would not bother with bootclasspath, I would simply call javac from JDK6

Comment: So I would need to copy my files directly in the JDK6 folder?

Comment: No, you call javac from JDK6, e.g. if you JDK6 is installed in C:\Java6 directory, you would call: c:\Java6\bin\javac